# Positive integer solutions of $(591-b-c-d)^2+(591-b-c-d)+41 = bcd$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Is there a non-numerical way to find the positive integer solutions of this equation: $(591-b-c-d)^2+(591-b-c-d)+41 = bcd$ ?

Numerically I know the answer is $b=47,c=53,d=71$ or a permutation of these values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is an original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint.

Show that $a^2+a+41$ is a prime number for all $2\leq a\leq39.$

Also, $a=40$ and $a=41$ they are not valid and for some numbers $a>41$ we get that $a^2+a+41$ is also prime.

Also, by AM-GM
$$a^2+a+41\leq\left(\frac{591-a}{3}\right)^3,$$ which gives $a\leq422.$

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how to solve the problem, since the desired $a$ is $420$ and there are a lot of numbers, composite or prime, between $40$ and $420$...

Comment: (In the above comment I meant the $a^2+a+41$ corresponding to each $a$ )

Comment: MichaelRozenberg, can I assume then that there is no better way than brute force for checking the values for $a$ from $40$ to $422$?

Comment: For $a\not\equiv0,-1(mod41)$ we'll get very many prime numbers in the form $a^2+a+41$ which is not valid.